# Elements of $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x_1, ..., x_n])$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I'm just curious as to what the elements of $\text{Spec}(R)$ are when $R = \mathbb{C}[x_1,..., x_n]$. I'm aware that $\text{MaxSpec}(R) = \mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: For every (irreducible) affine variety $V\subset \mathbb{C}^n$, there is a prime ideal in $R$ and vice versa. So $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ as a set contains a point for every irreducible subvariety of $\mathbb{C}^n$. There is a *zoo* of these subvarieties (many many many of them)! Impossible to describe all of them in just a few words.

Comment: @Hamed: You could turn that comment into an answer I think.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain I guess I can turn it into an answer, but I haven't said much, since not much can be said in full generality... I think leaving it as a comment is more appropriate...